# My deleteRows trigger is affecting my formula in Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a deleteRow trigger in my Google Sheet, but after it is executed is changes the range of my formula.

The deleteRow trigger:

```
function deleteRows() {
   var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Daily Attendance - inAcc'); 
   var start, howManyToDelete; 
   start = 2;
   howManyToDelete = sheet.getLastRow() - start + 1;
   sheet.deleteRows(start, howManyToDelete);
}
```

The formula which is affected:

How it should read:

```
={"TRIP 1 TIME";ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ISBLANK(D2:D),"",D2:D - C2:C))}
```

How it is reading after the trigger is executed:

```
={"TRIP 1 TIME";ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ISBLANK(D501:D),"",D501:D - C501:C))}
```

Any suggestions to avoid this problem?

Comment: Hi Mitch, I've had this problem in the past and have not found an easier solution than using .getFormula at the start of your script and then setFormula at the end. From what I understand, Google scripts and sheets don't talk to each other when it comes to this.

Comment: try using start=3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can write back the formula using scripts, try below:

Assuming the formula is entered in cell **E1**, change per your need

```
function deleteRows() {
   var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Daily Attendance - inAcc'); 
   var start, howManyToDelete; 
   start = 2;
   howManyToDelete = sheet.getLastRow() - start + 1;
   sheet.deleteRows(start, howManyToDelete);
   sheet.getRange('E1').setValue('={"TRIP 1 TIME";ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ISBLANK(D2:D),"",D2:D - C2:C))}')
   
}
```

Comment: The sheet.getRange works perfectly.